# Retrieve Portfolio Object through Soap Api

Tags: apex, marketing-cloud, soap-api, integration

When I was trying to integrate Marketing cloud to salesforce for Retrieving portfolio Object.
First Consume the WSDL file in Salesforce.
Then invoke this method:

```
WsdlToApexClass.Soap soapInst = new WsdlToApexClass.Soap();
```

`soapInst.endpoint_x = 'https://webservice.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx';
WsdlToApexClass.RetrieveRequest retrieveRequestInst = new WsdlToApexClass.RetrieveRequest();
list<WsdlToApexClass.ClientID> Lobj = new list<WsdlToApexClass.ClientID>(); 
WsdlToApexClass.ClientID obj = new WsdlToApexClass.ClientID();
    obj.ClientID ='client Id';// from connected App

Lobj.add(obj);
retrieveRequestInst.ClientIDs =Lobj;
retrieveRequestInst.ObjectType ='Portfolio';
soapInst.Retrieve_x(retrieveRequestInst);`

When I execute that code it will throw an error: "**System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: Security requirements are not satisfied because the security header is not present in the incoming message. faultcode=q0:Security faultactor=https://webservice.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx**"

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error - the request is missing the authentication header within the SOAP package.

There is a guide about SOAP API requests within the developers [page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/exacttarget_for_appexchange_api_guide.htm).

Here is the sample code that could help:

```
// 1a. Set the username/password. This is using the Username token of WS-Security 1.0
UsernameTokenProvider utp = new UsernameTokenProvider(<username>, <password>);
etForAppx.SetClientCredential<UsernameToken>(utp.GetToken());
```